# SwiftUI Preference Key to make uniformly sized boxes

Tags: swiftui

**UPDATE**: I've made this minimally reproducible.

I wish to make a grid for the alphabet, with each box the same size, looking like this:
[image: the desired grid]

I have a PreferenceKey, and a View extension, like this:

```
struct WidthPreference: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}
extension View {
    func sizePreference(letterIdx: Int) -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: WidthPreference.self, value: proxy.size.width)
        })
    }
}
```

My primary view is an HStack nestled in a VStack, with each letter as a separate view. Here is the ContentView, and its Alphabet Grid:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var theModel = MyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        AlphabetGrid()
            .textCase(.uppercase)
            .font(.body)
        
            .onAppear() {
                theModel.initializeLetters()
            }
            .environmentObject(theModel)
    }
}

struct AlphabetGrid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel
    
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8

    var body: some View {
        let theKeyboard = [ theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 0 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 1 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 2 }
        ]
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(theKeyboard, id: \.self) { keyboardRow in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    if let keyboardRow = keyboardRow {
                        ForEach(keyboardRow, id: \.self) { keyboardLetter in
                            let idx = keyboardLetter.letterStorePosition
                            LetterView(theIdx: idx, borderColour: .blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the Letter view, for each letter:

```
struct LetterView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel

    var theIdx: Int
    var borderColour: Color
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8

    @State private var cellWidth: CGFloat?  = nil
    
    func letterFor(letterIdx: Int) -> some View {
        Text(String(theModel.allLetters?[letterIdx].letterStoreChar ?? "*"))
            .sizePreference(letterIdx: letterIdx)
            .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth, alignment: .center)
            .padding(spacing)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        self.letterFor(letterIdx: theIdx)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke(borderColour, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreference.self) { self.cellWidth = $0 }
    }
}
```

Finally, for completeness, the Model to store the letters:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allLetters: [LetterData]?
    
    struct LetterData: Hashable {
        let letterStorePosition: Int
        let letterStoreChar: Character
        let keyboardRow: Int
        let keyboardCol: Int
    }
    
    let keyboardWide = 9 // characters per row
    
    // put all the alphabet characters into an array of LetterData elements
    func initializeLetters() {
        var tempLetters: [LetterData] = []
        let allChars = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        
        for (index, element) in allChars.enumerated() {
            let row = index / keyboardWide
            let col = index % keyboardWide
            tempLetters.append(LetterData(letterStorePosition: index, letterStoreChar: element,
                                          keyboardRow: row, keyboardCol: col))
        }
        allLetters = tempLetters
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes a pretty, yet incorrect grid like this:

[image: incorrect grid]

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is the answer your looking for how to make the evenly spaced grid, or how to use PreferenceKeys to do it?

Comment: Well! I think both would be very interesting to me! @AshleyMills

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, can you please create a [mcve]. The code you have supplied doesn't compile, and maybe you could wrap in a `struct ContentView` to show how it's presented.

Comment: Look into “Layout” it is a much better tool for this.

Comment: @AshleyMills - I've included the surrounding code, to make it minimally reproducible

Comment: @loremipsum - I look forward to learning how to do that!

Comment: Why is Ashley’s answer not the “right” answer?

Comment: @loremipsum - I will probably ultimately use Ashley's idea, but it does not help me better understand why my use of `PreferenceKeys` is incorrect

Comment: I went through your code today, see below for the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging, your PreferenceKey is being set with `.background` which just takes the size of the current `View` and you are using that value to turn into a square.

There is no match for the average just taking the current width and using it for the height.

```
extension View {
    func sizePreference(letterIdx: Int) -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: WidthPreference.self, value: proxy.size.width)
        })
    }
}

.frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth, alignment: .center)
```

The width is based on the letter `I` being the most narrow and `W` being the widest.

Now, how to "fix" your code. You can move the `onPreferenceChange` up one `View` and use the `min` between the current `cellWidth` and the `$0` instead of just replacing.

```
struct AlphabetGrid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel
    @State private var cellWidth: CGFloat  = .infinity
    
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        let theKeyboard = [ theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 0 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 1 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 2 }
        ]
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(theKeyboard, id: \.self) { keyboardRow in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    if let keyboardRow = keyboardRow {
                        ForEach(keyboardRow, id: \.self) { keyboardLetter in
                            let idx = keyboardLetter.letterStorePosition
                            LetterView(theIdx: idx, borderColour: .blue, cellWidth: $cellWidth)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }               .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreference.self) { self.cellWidth = min(cellWidth, $0 ?? .infinity) }
        
    }
}
```

Now with that fix you get a better looking keyboard but the M and W are cut off, to use the `max` you need a little more tweaking, ou can look at the code below.

```
import SwiftUI
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allLetters: [LetterData]?
    
    struct LetterData: Hashable {
        let letterStorePosition: Int
        let letterStoreChar: Character
        let keyboardRow: Int
        let keyboardCol: Int
    }
    
    let keyboardWide = 9 // characters per row
    
    // put all the alphabet characters into an array of LetterData elements
    func initializeLetters() {
        var tempLetters: [LetterData] = []
        let allChars = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        
        for (index, element) in allChars.enumerated() {
            let row = index / keyboardWide
            let col = index % keyboardWide
            tempLetters.append(LetterData(letterStorePosition: index, letterStoreChar: element,
                                          keyboardRow: row, keyboardCol: col))
        }
        allLetters = tempLetters
    }
}
struct AlphabetParentView: View {
    @StateObject var theModel = MyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        AlphabetGrid()
            .textCase(.uppercase)
            .font(.body)
        
            .onAppear() {
                theModel.initializeLetters()
            }
            .environmentObject(theModel)
    }
}
struct LetterView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel
    
    var theIdx: Int
    var borderColour: Color
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8
    
    @Binding var cellWidth: CGFloat?
    
    func letterFor(letterIdx: Int) -> some View {
        Text(String(theModel.allLetters?[letterIdx].letterStoreChar ?? "*"))
            .padding(spacing)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .stroke(borderColour, lineWidth: 1)
            .overlay {
                self.letterFor(letterIdx: theIdx)
            }
            .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth, alignment: .center)
        
    }
}
struct AlphabetGrid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel
    @State private var cellWidth: CGFloat?  = nil
    
    var spacing: CGFloat = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        let theKeyboard = [ theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 0 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 1 },
                            theModel.allLetters?.filter { $0.keyboardRow == 2 }
        ]
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(theKeyboard, id: \.self) { keyboardRow in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    if let keyboardRow = keyboardRow {
                        ForEach(keyboardRow, id: \.self) { keyboardLetter in
                            let idx = keyboardLetter.letterStorePosition
                            LetterView(theIdx: idx, borderColour: .blue, cellWidth: $cellWidth)
                                .sizePreference()
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }               .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreference.self) {
            if let w = cellWidth{
                self.cellWidth = min(w, $0 ?? .infinity)
            }else{
                self.cellWidth = $0
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct AlphabetParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AlphabetParentView()
    }
}

struct WidthPreference: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}
extension View {
    func sizePreference() -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: WidthPreference.self, value: proxy.size.width)
        })
    }
}
```

There are simpler way of handling this like Ashley's example or `SwiftUI.Layout` and layout but this should help you understand why your squares were uneven.

Comment: Both those solutions gave me very tall letter boxes! And, bypassed the PreferenceKey.

Comment: @coco limit he height to match the width

Comment: Setting the aspect ratio gives me square boxes, but they are not the same size as each other. I assume that would need to be stored somewhere (hence the idea of using the PreferenceKey)

Comment: @coco got it, look at Ashley's solution I would use Layout but that solution should work too.

Comment: Thank you, that does work, and helps me understand why mine didn't. And I agree, I'm not going to use this solution, but a modified Ashley grid makes the most sense

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple implementation, using a `GeometryReader` to allow us to calculate the width (and therefore the height), of each letter

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let letters = ["ABCDEFGHI","JKLMNOPQR","STUVWXYZ"]
    let spacing: CGFloat = 8

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(letters, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                        ForEach(Array(row), id: \.self) { letter in
                            Text(String(letter))
                                .frame(width: letterWidth(for: proxy.size.width), height: letterWidth(for: proxy.size.width))
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                        .stroke(.cyan, lineWidth: 1)
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
        
    func letterWidth(for width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let count = CGFloat(letters.map(\.count).max()!)
        return (width - (spacing * (count - 1))) / count
    }
}
```

[image]