# SwiftUI get frame before show content

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have wizard panel (sheet) compounds from 3 custom views which are switched based on buttons, but i don't know which panel has the biggest height at the beginning. Is there any option how to get frame of view before show? Thank you

I want to init all three views and set biggest height to parent view but i don't know how.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169812/swiftui-preference-key-to-make-uniformly-sized-boxes/75185538#75185538) may help you get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your views inside a `ZStack`, then show them as necessary. The `ZStack` will size to fit the largest subview. Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var viewIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            View1(index: $viewIndex)
                .opacity(viewIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            View2()
                .opacity(viewIndex == 1 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .background(.red)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @Binding var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is View 1")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Some other text")
            ProgressView()
            Button("Next") {
                index += 1
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is View 2")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. ")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            ProgressView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]